# Select * in a remote DB (MySQL) doesn't bring all the data

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

The query is simple -> "SELECT * FROM xxx";

When the result comes, it brings only the last result of the table instead all.

If I'm not mistaken, most remote databases come with a limit on the amount of data that is fetched, in order to avoid overflowing results.
But none of that is for sure, just my speculation.
Anyway, how to solve this?

```
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM favorite";

mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql);

mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

var_dump($row);
```

Comment: You should add all query codes in to question we cant help with that infos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_all($result);
```

```
mysqli_fetch_assoc();
```

only returns 1 row which explains why you only see the last row of the expected result set.

[mysqli_fetch_all](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)